# Problems with javascript centered elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my first question on stack overflow and I'm new to javascript/jquery so i will try my best to explain my problem.

I have two images that are animated into the centre of the browser on the x axis and these work fine on loading of the page. My problem occurs when I resize the browser after it has loaded. The elements do not stay in the center of the browser and are off center until I refresh the page and it works fine again.

I was wondering if there are any techniques to eradicate this issue?

Website can be viewed at www.puzzletest.click

Thank you in advance.

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div id="section1" class="section">
        <div>
            <img src="img/softsellcloud.png" class="ss-cloud" alt="Soft Sell Online - Business Automation Software">
            <img src="img/softselltext.png" class="ss-text" alt="Soft Sell Online - Business Automation Software">
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
            <h1>Business Automation Software.</h1>
            <h2>We Help Companies Work Smarter!</h2>
            <a href="tel:01772 842112"><img src="img/phone-log.png" alt="Phone Us Now"></a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="img/scroll-arrow.png" alt="Scrolling Arrow" id="arrow1" class="arrow">
        </div>
    </div>
```

My javascript code is this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#fullpage').fullpage();
    });

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ss-cloud").animate({
    left: $(".ss-cloud").parent().width() / 2 - $(".ss-cloud").width() / 2
    }, 2000);
    });

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ss-text").animate({
    right: $(".ss-text").parent().width() / 2 - $(".ss-text").width() / 2
}, 2000);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".caption" ).delay(2000).animate({
    opacity: 1,
  }, 3000, function() {
  });
});
```

Comment: See `.resize()` here: https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: I would recommend not to use javascript for this, but just nice css3. Example for positioning center{
left: 50%;
position: relative;
transform: translateX(-50%);}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the .resize function so the script fires everytime you resize your window.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
// Your code here
```

});

see also:
https://api.jquery.com/resize/